# Which alert timestamp (createTime or endTime) correlates to the time an email was "REMOVED_FROM_INBOX"

Tags: google-admin-sdk

Is anyone aware of which timestamp presented in alerts correlates to the actual time the email was removed from the inbox if the systemActionType states "REMOVED_FROM_INBOX"?

My question is specific to the "Gmail phishing" alert source (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/alert-types). I have yet to see an endTime that is after the alerts createTime for Phishing reclassification and a review of the  alert-types page and definitions makes me assume createTime is the correct time to utilize...... however that makes me confused on why there is an endTime being populated for these types.

| Key/Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Phishing reclassification | Unopened messages that are detected as phishing post-delivery are automatically reclassified and removed from the user's inbox. |
| createTime | Output only. The time this alert was created. |
| endTime | Optional. The time the event that caused this alert ceased being active. If provided, the end time must not be earlier than the start time. If not provided, it indicates an ongoing alert. |

Sample Alert

```
      "customerId": "<removed>",
      "alertId": "<removed>",
      "createTime": "2021-03-11T18:25:47.538082Z",
      "startTime": "2021-03-11T13:19:50.374062Z",
      "endTime": "2021-03-11T17:53:54.482936Z",
      "type": "Phishing reclassification",
      "source": "Gmail phishing",
      "data": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.alertcenter.type.MailPhishing",
        "domainId": {
          "customerPrimaryDomain": "<removed>"
        },
        "maliciousEntity": {
          "fromHeader": "<removed>"
        },
        "messages": [
          {
            "messageId": "<removed>",
            "md5HashMessageBody": "<removed>",
            "md5HashSubject": "<removed>",
            "attachmentsSha256Hash": [
              "<removed>"
            ],
            "recipient": "<removed>",
            "date": "2021-03-11T13:19:50.374062Z"
          }
        ],
        "isInternal": true,
        "systemActionType": "REMOVED_FROM_INBOX"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "customerId": "<removed>",
        "alertId": "<removed>",
        "status": "NOT_STARTED",
        "updateTime": "2021-03-11T18:25:47.538082Z",
        "severity": "MEDIUM",
        "etag": "<removed>"
      }
```

API Link if you so desire: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest/v1beta1/alerts

Comment: Considering that the `endTime` refers to the time when the event ceases to be active, one could think that's the time when the messages are removed from inbox. About `however that makes me confused on why there is an endTime being populated for these types`, if `endTime` was not populated this would be an ongoing event. In any case, do you have a way to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: I will see if I can have someone help reproduce, however if I am not able, are you able to ask internally which of the timestamps corresponds to the time an email from removed from the inbox?

Comment: It looks like the email is removed from the inbox when the actual alert is generated and notifies the admins. If this is not the case please let me know and I will mark as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

In `Phishing reclassification` alerts, the date when each message was removed from inbox (when it was reclassified) corresponds to the `date` field in each message:

```
{
 "data": {
   "messages": [
     {
       "date": "2021-03-11T13:19:50.374062Z"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

You will notice that it corresponds to the date in `startTime`. That’s because `startTime` corresponds to the date when the first message in the report was reclassified (since that’s the first and only reclassified message in this alert).

#### Reported in Issue Tracker:

The documentation at [GmailMessageInfo](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/alertcenter/reference/rest/v1beta1/GmailMessageInfo) is not clear on this, since `date` corresponds to `The date the malicious email was sent` only in some alert types.

Therefore, I reported a documentation bug in Issue Tracker:

- [[Alert Center API] Description of date in GmailMessageInfo not meaningful for all alert types](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187025258)

Comment: Thank you. I will mark this as answered for now and will watch the bug.